# FileUpload sem refresh na página?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, webforms

Percebi que é preciso um *refresh* na página inteira para obter o arquivo do lado do servidor.
Teria alguma forma sem *refresh* para realizar essa operação?
Sei que é possível com Ajax, como seria?

Comment: Marconi poderia colocar algum código que você fez relativo à pergunta? Assim as pessoas pode lhe ajudar de uma forma melhor.

Comment: Reaberto, respostas bem-vindas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui utilizando Ajax, não me lembro onde consegui o tutorial mais meu código ficou assim:

*HTML:*

```
 <form role="form" id="commentForm">
 <input type="file" id="uploadEditorImage" accept="image/*" />
 <button type="button" id="btnEnviar" data-loading-text="Enviando..." class="btn btn-primary">
   Enviar
 </button>
 </form>
```

*Ajax:*

```
$("#btnEnviar").click(function () { 
     var dataForm = new FormData($("#commentForm")[0]);
     var files = $("#uploadEditorImage").get(0).files;
     if (files.length > 0) {
            dataForm.append("HelpSectionImages", files[0]);
     }
     $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new { action = "EnviaArquivo", controller = "Home" })',
         type: "POST",
         processData: false,
         contentType: false,
         data: dataForm,
         success: function (response) {
                  console.log('sucesso');
                  console.log(response);    
                   },
         error: function (er) {
                  console.log('erro');
                  console.log(er);
         }
   });
});
```

*Controller:*

```
 [WebMethod]
 public string EnviaArquivo(FormCollection form)
 {           
     HttpPostedFile arquivo = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["HelpSectionImages"];
     string path = "~/img/fotosDepoimentos/";
     arquivo.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path + arquivo.FileName));         
     return "Arquivo enviado com sucesso...";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A forma que eu sempre recomendo é utilizando o ajaxuploader, ele é de graça e muito fácil de utilziar.

*observação: não é o ajax da microsoft*

link para o projeto

http://ajaxuploader.com/default.htm

como implementar
http://ajaxuploader.com/Deployment.htm

Comment: P/ mim que era de graça, é que só me mandaram aqui na empresa, aonde você viu que é pago?

Comment: http://ajaxuploader.com/download.htm ai fala que ele é pago após 30 dias.

Answer (score -1):

O problema acontece porque está ocorrendo um AsyncPostback, e para enviar o arquivo deve ser um PostBack comum. Assim, basta adicionar um PostbackTrigger forçar a atualização do UpdatePanel.

Supondo que exista um botão "Enviar" dentro do UpdatePanel, tente:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
      </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
         <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="EnviarBtn" />
      </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:Button ID="EnviarBtn" runat="server" />
```

Mais informações:

[FileUpload Doesn't Work When Nested In UpdatePanel? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107952/fileupload-doesnt-work-when-nested-in-updatepanel-c-sharp)

[Difference between PostBackTrigger and AsyncPostBackTrigger](http://forums.asp.net/t/1200349.aspx?Difference%20between%20PostBackTrigger%20and%20AsyncPostBackTrigger%20)