# $_FILES retornando vazio

Tags: php, javascript, html

Esse é o formulário que estou usando para enviar o arquivo

```
<form id="form_converter" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="arquivo" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>

$(document).on("submit", "#form_converter", function(){
    var dados  = $('#form_converter').serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sys/cv_unique_file.php",
        data: dados,
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

E no meu PHP

```
if(isset($_FILES)){
    print_r($_FILES);
}
```

E apenas recebo um array vazio `Array ()`, já cheque a permissão das pastas e ta tudo 777

Comment: Leo, a um tempo atrás eu fiz [assim](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32537/fileupload-sem-refresh-na-p%C3%A1gina), está em C# a parte do back-end. Na época eu precisei incluir o arquivo em `FormData`. Acho que com o exemplo você pode ajustar seu back-end. Espero que ajude :)

Comment: Relacionada: [Fazer upload de arquivo com AJAX](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9704/fazer-upload-de-arquivo-com-ajax)

Comment: Ralacionada: [Upload de imagem com Jquery](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130422/upload-de-imagem-com-jquery)

Comment: Relacionada: [upload sem refresh com FormData, jquery](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43405/upload-sem-refresh-com-formdata-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

a função `serialize()` não inclui campos do tipo `file` na "string query" gerada, suponhamos que em seu formulário você tivesse 2 campos do tipo `text`, deste modo o `serialize()` geraria uma `string` parecida com esta.

```
<form action="">
   <input type="text" name="nome">
   <input type="text" name="telefone">
   <input type="file" name="arquivo">
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>

$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   console.log($(this).serialize());
});

// Resultado do console.log: nome=aew&telefone=aew
```

Essa `string` gerada pelo `serialize()` é que sera enviada através do `ajax`.

Para enviar arquivos utilizando `ajax` você precisa usar a classe `FormData`, desta maneira:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   var formData = new FormData(this);

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "sys/cv_unique_file.php",
     data: formData,
     success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
     }
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Não sabia disso sobre o serialize(), mas sua função está retornando o seguinte erro: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation